# Flexible trace viewer (for etl files and runtime traces)

Tags: .net, logging, trace, diagnostics, etw

I'm looking for a trace viewer which will allow me to view ETL (Event Tracing for Windows) traces (created using WPP). I did found some ETL file viewers, but they **don't support looking at traces at runtime**.

I'm aware only of the TraceView.exe available at the DDK; but it lacks support for finding trace text, easy filtering per component or file, and changing log level at runtime.

Suggestions? Any decent .net tool written to support [.net usage of ETW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517330.aspx)?

Comment: If you're planing to use semantic logging ReflectInsight has an extension to log ETW messages to a live viewer. http://insightextensions.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [log2console](http://log2console.codeplex.com/). It can catch filter and display many different trace sources (file, tcp/ip, trace, ...)

Comment: downloaded log2console and only see there the option to use windows event log. How do you specify to use a GUID ETW and then the *.tmh files to decode WPP?

Comment: What is "guid etw" and "wpp" ?

Comment: You use the PDB file generated when the code is compiled to decode the traces generated for WPP (the preprocessror which insert ETW traces into the code easily).

Comment: sorry. log2console can only show/filter text files. I used it show/consolidate log4j and log4net generated log files

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look to [this](http://code.google.com/p/baical/) tools set. It allow to receive traces from ETW sessions, redirect them over network and it is more stable than ETViewer.

Answer (score 0):

After accepting the answer above as correct I find a better solution: [ETViewer from codeplex](http://etviewer.codeplex.com/). It is tailored to be used with WPP, extensible and easy-to-use.